# What compatibility issues are faced connecting java application using objdc with oracle and feasibility of connection?

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

Can anyone explain me feasibility of connecting java application with database in following scenarios?

Connecting

Java 4 application with ojbc14.jar with oracle 9i

Java 4 application with ojbc14.jar with oracle 18c

Java 4 application with ojbc8.jar with oracle 9i

Java 4 application with ojbc8.jar with oracle 18c

Java 8 application with ojbc14.jar with oracle 9i

Java 8 application with ojbc14.jar with oracle 18c

Java 8 application with ojbc8.jar with oracle 9i

Java 8 application with ojbc8.jar with oracle 18c

What issues will be faced if unable to connect in specific case from above?

Comment: [Oracle JDBC Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html)

Answer (score 1):

The number 14 in ojdbc14.jar implies that it was compiled with JDK1.4. Similarly, 8 on ojdbc8.jar implies it was compiled with JDK8. Therefore, you won't be able to use ojdbc8.jar with JDK1.4.

Regarding backward compatibility of the Oracle Server you can refer to this matrix extracted from Oracle support:

[image]

Comment: Does client version mean the version of ojdbc jar?

Comment: Yes ojdbc in the client. So you need to check which version your ojdbc8 or ojdbc14 jar is from. You can do so by doing "java -jar ojdbc14.jar" or "java -jar ojdbc8.jar". This should print the version of the library. As mentioned above "14" and "8" represent the version of the compiler not the version of the driver.